# http error 404.0 - not found in xampp server

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I've just downloaded xampp got everything set up and when i click admin button it takes to a webpage
and has the error sign
 http error 404.0- Not found 
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

Comment: Can you provide the xampp control panel screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Suzan, I can recommend you to use Wampserver instead of Xampp. Wampserver always works when ports 80, 3306 are NOT in use. Else you would have to set the VirtualHost to listen to port 8080 or any other free port. For that I can give you instructions if you need.

I think that a 404 can only be caused by the webserver alias or port configuration. Check the XAMPP management window and check whether Apache is running on 80 or 1337 or another port. If you find the port number, type:

http://localhost:PORTNUMBERHERE/phpmyadmin

When the webserver is running on port 80 or 443, you would not have to type

http://localhost:80/phpmyadmin, because that is the default protocol. Port 443 is the default protocol for SSL, so you would get https://localhost/phpmyadmin instead of https://localhost:443/phpmyadmin. With any other number you have to type it.